# Screen Width too small in iPython terminal

Tags: python, css, ipython

My iPython will show a list as one tall column if it is too long. I want it to take full use of the terminal's screen width. I know it is not a terminal issue because terminal output will take use of the full screen. I have already tried editing '.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css' to have '.container { width:100% !important; }' with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have an output like

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

instead of

```
[1,
2,
3,
4]
```

?

If so: start ipython with the `--no-pprint` flag or use `%pprint` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010036/how-to-make-ipython-output-a-list-without-line-breaks-after-elements)).

Comment: YES! Exactly, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, so that this question is marked as answered.