# Controlling list visualisation in IPython

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, ipython

## Question

IPython decides to show lists vertically (and forces you to scroll a lot) when these are wider than the current screen. See below

```
In [1]: list(range(20))
Out[1]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

In [2]: list(range(30))
Out[2]: 
[0,
 1,
 2,
 ...
 27,
 28,
 29]
```

Whereas Python shows them always horizontally.
Is there a way to control this behaviour in IPython? I couldn't find anything online. Maybe I've been using bad keywords.

## Duplicate at posteriori

Alright. Now that I got an answer I also found out (using the `pprint` keyword) that this question is a duplicate of [How to make Ipython output a list without line breaks after elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19010036/2247039).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control that using the command `%pprint`.

As you wrote,

```
list(range(30))
```

yields

```
[0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
...
 27,
 28,
 29]
```

If you then enter

```
%pprint
```

you will read the message

```
Pretty printing has been turned OFF
```

And then

```
list(range(30))
```

becomes:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

Alternatively, you can also just type

```
print(list(range(30))
```

which gives you also the horizontal output.

Comment: Thank you. The behaviour was due `%pprint`. I'm using Python 3, so I still need to build a `list` out of a `range` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using pprint's pformat function.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely work around by using just `print`.

But for your problem, it is related with the maximum line width setting of IPython interactive terminal.

Just edit or create IPython configuration file `ipython_config.py` in ipython default config dir (typically located in `~/.ipython/profile_default/`). Adding the following lines, then restart your IPython in terminal.

```
c = get_config()
# the default is 79, modify it to any max line width you like
# list repr string larger than it will be wrapped to display vertically
c.PlainTextFormatter.max_width = 100
```

See [Introduction to IPython configuration](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html) and [ipython: how to set terminal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583428/ipython-how-to-set-terminal-width).