# Jupyter / Python display list with or without line breaks

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, line-breaks

In Jupyter notebook I entered the following command and the resulting list was displayed with(!) line breaks:

[image]

Some time later I entered the exact same command and now the resulting list is displayed without(!) line breaks:

[image]

Here some example code to create a list using Counter:

```py
from collections import Counter
import string as string

Counter(string.ascii_lowercase).most_common()
```

I know I can print the elements with line breaks using for example:

```
print(*Counter(string.ascii_lowercase).most_common(), sep='\n')
```

But the purpose of my question is not to get a solution but to understand why I got different results. (I guess I changed a display setting somewhere but I have no idea which one.)

**Update 1:**
Can anybody see the screenprints? (I only see links to images which appear to be dead..)
Explanation (added later): Screenprints could not be displayed because of the firewall of my company. They are however visible on my private laptop so they were uploaded. (See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64402/cannot-see-pictures-on-stack-overflow.)

**Update 2:**
I adjusted the examples to make the data anonymous.

Comment: My guess would be that you have used the [`%pprint`](https://ipythonbook.com/magic/pprint.html) command between those two moments, which toggles pretty printing. I.e. your first snippet is with pprint ON, second is with pprint OFF. Check, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010036/how-to-make-ipython-output-a-list-without-line-breaks-after-elements.

Comment: @ouroboros1 You're right!! I did use pprint in between. I used it again which toggled it ON and now I get the first snippet again. Thanks a lot, I am pretty amazed you solved this.

Comment: @ouroboros1 If you post your solution in a formal answer, I'd be happy to accept and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help. I think it's best to flag this one as a duplicate. There's also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194659/controlling-list-visualisation-in-ipython. Same idea. Happy coding